# Is it possible to define a "shared" method for C# interfaces?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, .net-3.5

Say I have 4 classes: `Foo`, `Bar`, `Qux`, and `Baz`. I also have an interface `IFubar`.

The classes inherit from one another like so:

```
Bar : Foo, IFubar

Qux : Baz, IFubar
```

The methods in `IFubar` will almost always be implemented the same way, no matter what class is inheriting them. The ideal solution would be to have the implementation in `IFubar` itself, but I can't change `IFubar` to a class because `Bar` and `Qux` *have* to inherit from `Foo` and `Baz`, respectively, and C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Is there an easy way to have some sort of "default" logic in an interface, for lack of a better term? Right now my "implementation" is just a call to a static method in another class, which allows me to perform all my logic there and minimize code duplication. I feel like that's not an elegant solution, however.

Ideally, I'd like to have a class derive from some class and `IFubar` and have it automatically get the same `IFubar` implementation without me having to copy and paste. I'm fairly certain that sort of thing isn't possible with C#, but I want to make sure.

Honestly, it's nothing more than a mild annoyance that I have to copy and paste the same code over and over again, but I've been trying to think of a more elegant solution and I can't.

This would all be for something used in the Unity3D engine, so [I'm limited to things in .NET 3.5, mostly.](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html)

Does anyone have any better solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Can't you change `IFubar` to a class and have `*Foo*` and `*Baz*` inherit from that (rather than `Bar` and `Qux`) to avoid the multiple inheritence issue?

Comment: @petelids As I mentioned below in the answer that suggested this, part of the problem is that I rely on `obj as IFubar` returning null when `obj` is an instance of `Foo` or `Baz`, while having it successfully cast to an `IFubar` instance when `obj` is an instance of `Bar` or `Qux`. Additionally, in the actual implementation of this, there are close to a dozen classes which implement `IFubar`, all of which inherit from various other classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "almost always" is the problem. If it was "always", then an "extension method" would be ideal:

```
public static class FubarExtensions
{
    public static void SomeMethod(this IFubar obj) { ... }
}
```

If you need the "almost", they you probably need polymorphism for it to be *reliable*. In that case, using a static method for the default implementation is probably your best option, i.e.

```
IFubar.SomeMethod(...)
{
    Fubar.SomeMethodDefault(this, ...);
}
```

or:

```
public virtual void SomeMethod(...)
{
    Fubar.SomeMethodDefault(this, ...);
}
```

(or any similar combination)

Comment: Hmm. Extension methods seem fairly close to what I'd like to accomplish -- there are very few cases where my default implementation wouldn't be ideal, and those few cases can be handled on their own fairly easily, so I'm marking this as my answer. [The MSDN docs on the matter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) say "An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface or class method will never be called." This means I would need to get rid of the abstract version of the method in the `IFubar` interface to ensure the extension method gets called, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation is always the same then you could use something like this:

```
class Fubar : IFubar {
    public void SomeIFubarMethod() { … }
}

class Foo : Fubar { … }

class Baz : Fubar { … }
```

Then you can use the same inheritance for `Bar` and `Qux` (and you don't even need to specify the `IFubar` interface again):

```
class Bar : Foo { … }

class Qux : Baz { … }
```

Comment: I would like to do something like that, but the issue with that approach is `Foo` and `Baz` could be successfully cast to `IFubar` -- which isn't ideal for my circumstance. Part of the implementation of this relies on `obj as IFubar` returning null when an object doesn't inherit `IFubar`.